# ActionScript 3 if condition error

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, flash-cs4

I have the following code in my game:

```
var type:Number = Math.random() * 1000;
var lifeCoinLevel:Number = 1;
var lives:Number = 2;
var maxLives:Number = 3;
var coins:Array = new Array();

if(lifeCoinLevel > 0 && lives < maxLives && (type >= 255 && type <= 345)) {
    coins[1] = new LifeCoin();
}

coins[1].x = Math.random() * 350 + 145;
```

I got this error when run the game:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no
>   properties.
>    at
>   MoneyCatcher_fla::MainTimeline/CreateNewCoin()
>     at
>   Function/http ://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
>       at
>   SetIntervalTimer/onTimer()
>     at
>   flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

It seems like the if condition not met, but I don't know why. Any thoughts?

Comment: the code you posted has nothing to do with the error you posted. the error comes from a faulty `Timer` setup. Show us `CreateNewCoin()`

Comment: may be that portion of code is from ` CreateNewCoin ` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should do like this :

```
...

if(lifeCoinLevel > 0 && lives < maxLives && (type >= 255 && type <= 345)) {
    coins[1] = new LifeCoin();
    coins[1].x = Math.random() * 350 + 145;
}
```

because if the condition is not true, the `coins[1]` is undefined and then you get an error.